# Error in using polar coordinates to prove the existence of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is to show the limit exists: 
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2ye^y}{x^4+4y^2}$ 

I already know that the limit doesn't exist, bc. if I use the equations $x^2 = y$  and $x = 0$ on different limits they give a different result (1/5 and 0, respectively). But, if I use polar coordinates (with $x = rcos\theta, y = rsin\theta$) the limit results in; 
$\lim_{r\to0} \frac{r^2cos^2\theta sin\theta e^{rsin\theta}}{r^4cos^2 \theta + 4r^2 sin^2 \theta} = \lim_{r\to0} \frac{0}{4 sin^2 \theta} = 0$ 

And I don't understand where the polar coordinates are wrong.

Comment: The expression when $r\to 0^+$ behaves like ${\cos^2\theta\over 4\sin\theta}$ so the limit does not exist. I prefer  modified polar coordinates: $x^2=r\cos\theta,$ $2y=r\sin\theta. $